# json write zero leading decimal strings producing strange output

Tags: python, json

I have a problem that is difficult to describe because I cannot develop a small example that produces the error that I getting.  I can however, describe the circumstances.

The following simple code works:

```
import json

data = ("0.5 cup corn")

with open('iam_working.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(data, json_file, sort_keys=True,  ensure_ascii=True, indent = 4)
```

This works as expected, I get the following:

```
[
    "0.5 cup corn",
    "1 cup flour"
]
```

However, in my large process where I am processing a couple of thousand lines I get an output like (as viewed in an editor):

```
[
    "0.\u00025 cup corn",
    "1 cup flour"
]
```

Where it appears the `0.5` is being replaced with a special character.  BTW, I need the leading `0` (ie `0.5` not `.5`) because of some later NLP work.

In my larger process, I have added a couple of test lines:

```
print(myStr)
print('type: ', type(myStr))
```

These produce the string as expected:

```
"0.5 cup corn"

type:  <class 'str'>
```

When I read json file back and print the string all looks fine with these prints -- ie `"0.5"`

However, if I try to convert the token to a float with: `float(myStr)`.

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.\x025'
```

I need to determine what is causing these special character of my decimal numbers or at a minimum determine how to get the `float()` to work.

Comment: Are your lines coming from a file? `\u0002` is the unicode for "start of text" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Control_codes), which means it's in the string you posted. When you print it, it shows fine (try `print("0.\u00025")`), but it cannot be parsed as float.

Comment: Seems like you have the byte ``\x02'` in your data. This might not be shown in your editor, but it's there.

Comment: Thanks, those comments make sense.  I am doing a RegEx sub statement to produce the strings.  I will concentrate on that to see if I can determine the issue.

Comment: @jz_ That sounds like you might have some replacement strings with group references that need to be changed to raw strings - i.e. `'\2'` => `r'\2'`.

Comment: There is no `"1 cup flour"` in your example. What version of Python are you using? Python 2 is notoriously trickier with UTF, if you're on 2, consider 3.

Comment: Sorry,  the "1 cup flour" line is working correctly.  I should have added that.  I am using 3.

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to RegEx.  Actually, incorrectly referencing a substring.  In RegEx101.com test, the error showed, but gave a warning.  In Python, it seemed to execute, but did not give the expected results. For the record here is the faulty line.

```
myStr = re.sub("(?<![0-9])\.+(?=[0-9])", "0.\2", myStr)
```

It was replaced with:

```
 myStr = re.sub("(?<![0-9])\.+(?=[0-9])", "0.", myStr)
```

Comment: It doesn't give an error, because you aren't using raw strings. If you had, it would have raised an invalid group reference error. Failing to use raw strings in regexp patterns is a very common bug trap.